# flexplot package in R: Why are R-squared and ICC values different from other packages?

Tags: r, mixed-models

I am trying to get to know the `flexplot` package in order to use it for my own analysis. However when comparing the `flexplot` results for the R2 and the ICC to computations from the `performance` package I get different results (except when it's an intercept-only model).

For example let's look at a simple one predictor model:

(The dataset is from: https://quantpsych.net/data/jedi.csv)

```
library(lme4)
library(flexplot)

jedi <- read.csv("jedi.csv")
model <- lmer(darkness ~ anger + (1|dojo_id), data = jedi)

performance::icc(model)                              # ICC = .275
performance::r2(model)                               # R2  = .319 (marginal)
                                                     # R2  = .506 (conditional)

# flexplot
estimates(model)                                     # ICC = .177
#                                                    # R2  = .390 (Residual)
                           
# ICC: Calculation by hand
variance.components <- data.frame(VarCorr(model))$vcov
variance.components[1]/sum(variance.components)      # ICC = .275
```

I think the ICC in `flexplot` might always return the ICC computed in the intercept-only model, but I don't understand how the R2 is computed or what it means. There is also an R2 for `(Intercept)`, which in this example is negative, so I'm not sure what this means either.
Interpretation of the marginal (and conditional) R2 in the `performance` package is given by this [source](https://easystats.github.io/performance/articles/r2.html).

> The marginal R-squared considers only the variance of the fixed effects [...], while the conditional R-squared takes both the fixed and random effects into account [...].

Does someone have experience with `flexplot` and knows how these values are computed or what exactly they mean?